# Java static variable - difference between Foo.var = value and var = value?

Tags: java, static, thread-safety

In Java I have a static variable in a class.

```
public class Foo {

    private static Object var;
    ...

    public void setVar(Object newValue) {
        Foo.var = newValue;
        //Or:
        var = newValue;
    }
```

In a method (not static) where I change the value of the variable, what is going to be the difference between using:

```
Foo.var = newValue;
```

And:

```
var = newValue;
```

The code is in a threaded environment and I imagine that this is where it will make any difference.

Comment: The only place the different notation will make a difference is when `var` is `final` and you try to use it as a value before it is initialized.

Comment: (There's also a difference when the identifier `var` is shadowed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is in the Foo class then the two lines are equivalent. It *might* be slightly better to reference this as Foo.var, just so that in the event that Foo gets subclassed and the code changing it is moved to a subclass of Foo, that it was clear that it was referencing a variable in Foo and not in a subclass that shadowed var with another variable with the same name. If you have code in a subclass of Foo that references a variable in Foo then a static variable in the subclass with the same name will be seen by the subclass code instead of the one in Foo, if the explicit class reference is missing. But otherwise the two lines are the same.

If you are changing something accessed by multiple threads you should make sure that it is either volatile, an atomic reference, or something changed and read by threads acquiring the same lock. Otherwise updates to it may not be visible to other threads. But as long as no variable shadowing is involved, referencing it with the class name or not won't by itself make a difference, it definitely won't affect the memory visibility of updates by multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your code is really in the `Foo` class, `var` and `Foo.var` mean exactly the same thing. In fact, some IDEs will actually warn you about prefixing `var` with `Foo.` is redundant.